# Optional C# parameter issue

Tags: c#

I have this method

```
public static void WriteErrorLog(LogEntry logEntry, string method, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(0)]  int? errorTypeID)
```

So I expect that I can call the method like

```
WriteErrorLog(l, "text");
```

But I get an error of Visual Studio anyway :(

> No overload for method 'WriteErrorLog' takes 2 arguments

What I am missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Which .NET framework do you compile for?

Comment: Unable to reproduce in VS2012rc, .NET 4.5 - which versions (VS, .NET, etc) are you using?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have used VS2010 .NET 4.0

Comment: @Peretz, it'd be really useful if you posted a full program, even if it's just a LinqPad snippet that worked correctly.  Not that we need it for this particular case, it's just a friendly formality.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're not supposed to be using `[Optional, DefaultParameterValue(0)]`. Instead, you should use the c-style default parameter syntax:

```
public static void WriteErrorLog(LogEntry logEntry, string method, int? errorTypeID = 0)
```

Also, if `errorTypeId` is a `Nullable`, then shouldn't you have the default value be `null`?

```
public static void WriteErrorLog(LogEntry logEntry, string method, int? errorTypeID = null)
```

Answer (score 6):

You're problem is that `[Optional]` is not how you make it optional.  Try:

```
public static void WriteErrorLog(LogEntry logEntry, string method, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(0)]  int? errorTypeID = null)
```

Optional parameters were added in C# 4.0 and are a simple alternative to method overloading.  Under the hood it gets expanded where you call it to a call including the default value you give it.  You can leave the `[Optional]` attribute.  It doesn't hurt at all. In fact, I'm not sure if it does anything at all. If I had to guess it was to make overloads easier to use by marking ones that could be omitted because another overload handled the default for you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to state optional parameters this way:

```
public static void WriteErrorLog(LogEntry logEntry, 
    string method, int? errorTypeID = 0)
```

This will compile properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use .NET 4 (or newer):

```
public static void WriteErrorLog(LogEntry logEntry, string method, int? errorTypeID = null)
```

Note that the "default" value for a nullable type is `null`. In C, people usually use -1 or 0 as the default value of integers, this is what you can do more cleanly in C# with nullables. AFAIK there is something similar in Haskell, and other languages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it isn't working for you. I copied the method parameters exactly how you typed them. I use VS2010 and .NET 4.0. I ran the code and it works just fine every time.

You should be using the C-style default parameters anyhow. But this method still works for me. I get a red underline, however, and hovering displays the same error. But when I run the code everything works as it should.